# Can't send log into Graylog kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress, nginx-ingress, graylog3

How to expose node port on ingress?

```
NAME                         TYPE        CLUSTER-IP    EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)                                       AGE
logs-graylog                 NodePort    10.20.8.187   <none>        80:31300/TCP,12201:31301/UDP,1514:31302/TCP   5d3h
logs-graylog-elasticsearch   ClusterIP   None          <none>        9200/TCP,9300/TCP                             5d3h
logs-graylog-master          ClusterIP   None          <none>        9000/TCP                                      5d3h
logs-graylog-slave           ClusterIP   None          <none>        9000/TCP                                      5d3h
logs-mongodb-replicaset      ClusterIP   None          <none>        27017/TCP                                     5d3h
```

This is how my service look like where there are some node ports.
 Graylog web interface is expose on port 80.

But i am not able to send logs on URL. my graylog weburl is https://logs.example.com

it's running on https cert-manager is there on kubernertes ingress.

i am not able to send Glef UDP logs on URl. am i missing something to open port from ingress or UDP filter something ?

this is my ingress :

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: logs-graylog-ingress
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx
    certmanager.k8s.io/cluster-issuer: graylog
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/ssl-redirect: "true"

spec:
  tls:
  - hosts:
    - logs.example.io
    secretName: graylog
  rules:
  - host: logs.example.io
    http:
      paths:
      - backend:
          serviceName: logs-graylog
          servicePort: 80
      - backend:
          serviceName: logs-graylog
          servicePort: 12201
      - backend:
          serviceName: logs-graylog
          servicePort: 31301
```

Service :

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:

  labels:
    app: graylog
    chart: graylog-0.1.0
    component: graylog-service
    heritage: Tiller
    name: graylog
    release: logs
  name: logs-graylog

spec:
  clusterIP: 10.20.8.187
  externalTrafficPolicy: Cluster
  ports:
  - name: http
    nodePort: 31300
    port: 80
    protocol: TCP
    targetPort: 9000
  - name: udp-input
    nodePort: 31301
    port: 12201
    protocol: UDP
    targetPort: 12201
  - name: tcp-input
    nodePort: 31302
    port: 1514
    protocol: TCP
    targetPort: 1514
  selector:
    graylog: "true"
  sessionAffinity: None
  type: NodePort
status:
  loadBalancer: {}
```

Comment: The ingress controller that the http is going via is not able to forward a UDP port. You need to expose the UDP port to outside the cluster somehow. What does your nginx ingress Service use for the external access? A load balancer?

Comment: @Matt you are absolutely right service is not exposed ingress routing the web traffic to service on port 80. I have created NodePort but no idea how to expose node port on ingress.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

UDP services aren't normally exposed via an Ingress Controller like TCP HTTP(S) services are. I'm not sure any ingress controllers even support UDP, certainly not with 3 protocols combined in a single ingress definition.

If the cluster is hosted on a cloud service, most support a [Service with type `LoadBalancer`](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/#loadbalancer) to map external connections into a cluster.

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: logs-direct-graylog
spec:
  selector:
    graylog: "true"
  ports:
  - name: udp-input
    port: 12201
    protocol: UDP
    targetPort: 12201
  - name: tcp-input
    port: 1514
    protocol: TCP
    targetPort: 1514
  type: LoadBalancer
```

If service of type `LoadBalancer` is not available in your environment you can use the NodePort service. The `nodePort`s you have defined will be available on the external IP of each of your nodes.

A `nodePort` is not strictly required for the http port, as the nginx Ingress Controller takes care of that for you elsewhere in it's own service.

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: logs-graylog
spec:
  selector:
    graylog: "true"
  ports:
  - name: http
    port: 80
    protocol: TCP
    targetPort: 9000
```

The ports other than 80 can be removed from your ingress definition.

Comment: I have did same created two service one having port 80 another having 12201 with Loadbalancer type so directly sending logs on Loadbalancer IP.